# Error while installing - composer require socialiteproviders/twitch

Tags: laravel, twitch, laravel-socialite

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for socialiteproviders/twitch ^3.0 -> satisfiable by socialiteproviders/twitch[v3.0.0].
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - socialiteproviders/twitch v3.0.0 requires socialiteproviders/manager ~3.0 -> satisfiable by socialiteproviders/manager[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4].
>       - socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.0 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6].
>       - socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.1 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6].
>       - socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.2 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6].
>       - socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.3 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6].
>       - socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.4 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.4 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.5 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.6 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.3.31, required as 5.3.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.31].

Answer (score 0):

As the error states Its a version compatibility issue.laravel socialite version does not match with the version of the package you are trying to install. Install the required version.either change the version of the package you are trying to install or the version of the laravel.

Comment: It says its locked at that version What should I do is there anyway to install it?

Comment: Delete the composer.lock file if it requires.

Comment: The problem is I have laravel socialite and socialitemanager along with instagram already installed and they are all interdependent, I am not able to uodate any of those files, if i update socialite it says socialitemanger need that version and viceversa, also I tried deleting composer.lock, and also deleting all the files nothing works. Not sure what to do .